# discord.py nextcord.py It cant read mp3 audio files

Tags: python, ffmpeg, nextcord

I'm trying to make my discord bot speak some text, but I can't make it stream the generated mp3 audio file. I'm using Nextcord and FFmpeg.

This is the code I run :

```py
@bot.command(name="bottalk")
async def bottalk(ctx, *args):
    text = " ".join(args)
    user = ctx.message.author
    if user.voice != None:
        try:
            vc = await user.voice.channel.connect()

        except:
            vc = ctx.voice_client   

        sound = gTTS(text=text, lang="en", slow=False)  
        sound.save("please read this.mp3")

        if vc.is_playing():
            vc.stop()

        source = await nextcord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe("please read this.mp3", method="fallback")
        vc.play(source)
    else:
        await ctx.send("join vc")
```

When I run the code it generates the mp3 audio file but cannot play the audio file. I get this error :

```py
Ignoring exception in command bottalk:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gmmz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 165, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\gmmz5\OneDrive\เดสก์ท็อป\python\qweqwewqeqewqe\hi.py", line 4
5, in tts
    source = await nextcord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe("please read this.mp3", method="fallback")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\gmmz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\player.py", line 496, in from_probe
    return cls(source, bitrate=bitrate, codec=codec, **kwargs)  # type: ignore           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\gmmz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\player.py", line 426, in __init__
    super().__init__(source, executable=executable, args=args, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gmmz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\player.py", line 165, in __init__
    self._process: subprocess.Popen = self._spawn_process(args, **kwargs)     
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     
  File "C:\Users\gmmz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\player.py", line 184, in _spawn_process
    raise ClientException(executable + " was not found.") from None
nextcord.errors.ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gmmz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1381, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\gmmz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 948, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gmmz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\ext\commands\core.py", line 174, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: 
ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.
Exception ignored in: <function AudioSource.__del__ at 0x0000022C43A47BA0>    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gmmz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\player.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.cleanup()
  File "C:\Users\gmmz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\player.py", line 235, in cleanup
    self._kill_process()
  File "C:\Users\gmmz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\player.py", line 191, in _kill_process
    proc = self._process
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'FFmpegOpusAudio' object has no attribute '_process'
```

Comment: Hey, Welcome to S.O Have you confirmed that you have `ffmpeg` installed?

Comment: @NewtonKaranu you mean pip install ffmpeg-python or pip install ffmpeg right ? yes i do it

Comment: No, I mean installing it on your computer. From your stack trace, `ffmpeg` is not installed. Try and follow this link [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ffmpeg-windows) to install it on your computer. Don't forget to add it to `$PATH` afterwards.

Comment: @NewtonKaranu yes i installed it now , but still not work

Comment: @NewtonKaranu still got

File "C:\Users\gmmz5\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\nextcord\player.py", line 184, in _spawn_process
    raise ClientException(executable + " was not found.") from None
nextcord.errors.ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

and all code erorr is same as above before